# SQL Query to Build SRRS Dynamics 365 Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to develop some SSRS reports on Dynamics 365 On-Premise.

Can you please help me out on queries to achieve the below outputs.

**Table 1 :**

```
HOD id  ||  HOD Name   ||  Section <br>
1              A           Section1 <br>
2              B           Section2  <br>
```

**Table2 :**

```
Case ID||Case Number||Section|| Created on|| Modified On||Status Code||SLA name <br>

101         123      Section1 01/09/2018 01/09/2018    In Progress    TestSLA <br>
102         124      Section1 02/09/2018 05/09/2018    Resolved       TESTSLA
<br>
103         125      Section2 01/09/2018 01/09/2018    InProgress     TestSLA <br>
```

**OUTPUT1:**

[image: Output 1]

**OUTPUT 2**
[image: Output 2]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When posting a question it's really important to actually ask a qusetion. What is your question here? What have you tried so far to answer said question? What problems have you had? For the second dataset, SQL Server can't create merged cells, and I recommend against creating "gap rows". That will need to be handled in your presentation layer.

Comment: Which versions are you using? Also check this out for some help on question asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dynamics 365, You should be using FetchXMl quires and not sql for developing Reports. Here is the Video tutorial [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgHUY2tVCz0) for Creating SSRS Reports.

Now let's Lead you close to achive your solution.

1. Create a Fetchxml query where you link your Table 1 and Table 1
   based on Section (and join type should be Inner)
2. In Visual Studio Data tools for SSRS you will find lot's of different ways to represent/manipulate your Data. To achieve Output 1 you could  Group the Rows by Section and IT will appear only single row per Group. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keBOCdMfelU)  is one more simple tutorial for grouping.